# Use only available SOAP bindings?

Tags: python, soap

Currently using Suds with Python 2.7. Open to trying a different client.

I'm connecting to a SOAP service that returns different documents where only certain fields are available depending on the document. Introspecting the service doesn't help because I just get a list of all available fields rather than those returned on a doc by doc basis. This has led me to some particularly annoying error handling, which currently looks like:

```
try:
    client.service.Something
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    doSomethingWith(client.service.Something)
```

For every possible field in the WSDL schema.

Alternatively, parsing the response to generate a list of available fields doesn't help much, because then I end up with a long list of

```
if client.service.Something is not None:
    doSomethingWith(client.service.Something)
```

I suppose I could parse the doc and build a list of available fields, and then do something like:

```
for field in listOfFields:
    doSomethingWith(field)
```

But I do different things with the field's contents depending on what the field is, so that doesn't help much.

Is there any simple/elegant solution? I can't be the only one to have encountered this.